# Django framework form is trying to insert a new record instead of updating

Tags: django, model, insert, unique

Django 1.11.4 python 3.6

I have a default Django framework form I use for both update and create records for a given model. The primary key ("id" field) is generated by Django. The rest is defined in my model (see below). The model is subclassed from AuditModel class which overloads `save` method.
Everything works at this point, i.e. I can create new records or update existing records using standard Django forms interface.

```
class Product(AuditModel):

    internal_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, help_text="Internal ID")

    external_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False, help_text="External ID", verbose_name="External ID")

    label = models.ForeignKey(Label, help_text="Label")

class AuditModel(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(null=True,editable=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(null=True,editable=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        date = timezone.localtime()

        if self._state.adding :
            self.created = date
        self.updated = date
        super(AuditModel, self).save()
```

My question: I would like external_id to be unique (but not a primary key), i.e.

`external_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, null=False, blank=False, help_text="External ID", verbose_name="External ID")`

Once I added `unique=True` to the definition of the `external_id` field, the behaviour of the view changes: on attempt to update existing record I get an error message next to `external_id` textbox "Product with this External ID already exists." and no change happens in the DB. Somehow presence of `unique=True` in the definition of the `external_id` field make Django to think that I am not editing an existing record but arrived to this form to create a new entry.

The url I arrived to the screen with is correct, i.e `/product/<some id here>/change/`, not `/product/add`

In the DB all the existing values in `external_id` field are non-null (no empty strings either) and unique.

If I understood correctly by adding some debug, the error "Product with this External ID already exists" happens **BEFORE** `save()` is even called, like `unique=True` invokes some Django data validator that happened to be unaware of the current action (update vs insert) and the view is just reloaded with an error.

Answer (score 0):

Solved - The problem was caused by commented out line `# instance._state.adding = False` inside `def from_db()` method of a superclass. No idea why it got commented out.